# Granting a reviewer permission to delete feature branch while completing a PR

Tags: azure-devops

After approving a PR, can a reviewer be allowed to delete the source `feature` branch (during merging)? `feature` branch is created off `develop` branch. We want reviewer to be able to delete `feature` branch. However, reviewer should not be able to delete `develop` branch while merging that to `master` branch.

Is that possible with Azure DevOps? How can we set the branch policy/security to achieve the above?

Addition: `feature` branch can indeed be deleted provided branch owner is the one completing the PR (there is a checkbox to do that). We want to shift that responsibility to reviewer who does not really own the feature branch. (The checkbox is disabled for reviewer with *insufficient permissions* message.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the reviewer the permission to delete the branch, you need to enable the delete branch permission in the Repositories' setting. Please check below steps:

Go to **Project settings** -> **Repos** -> **Repositories** -> Select your **repository**.

On the **Security** page of your repository, Search the user you want to grant the delete branch permission in the search box.

[image]

On the Security page of the selected user, Set the **Force push** permission to **Allow**. Then the delete checkbox for the reviewer will be enabled.

[image]

> Update:

If you want to enable multiple reviewers the delete permission. You can go to **Organization settings**, click **Permissions** under **Security**, Click **New group** to create a new Group(eg.Reviewers) and add the reviewers to this group.

Then follow above steps enable the branch deletion permission for this Group. The reveiwers in this Group will automatically inherit this deletion permission.

Comment: So, I have to do it for each reviewer at individual branch's security page? I would like some inheritance or so. I can have a new role **Reviewers**. Is it possible to automatically let **Reviewers** delete `feature` branches?

Comment: Yes, the reviewer in Reviewers role will inherit the delete permission. I updated above answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have finally managed to confirm that your suggested solution works well.

Answer (score 0):

Having any branch policy on `develop` would mean that it can't be deleted when completing a PR to `master`. Branches with policies set are inelgible for deletion as part of PR completion.

Comment: You're right that `develop` branch will not be deleted since it has policies defined. What about `feature` branch that is based on `develop`? `feature` branch can indeed be deleted provided branch owner is the one completing the PR. We want to shift that responsibility to reviewer who does not really own the `feature` branch.

Comment: Any recommendations on how to allow for deletion in this scenario without essentially nullifying the point of the policy. That is, don't set the "override policy" permission for users to be able to delete the branch.